# Arabic / Hebrew and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, arabic, hebrew, right-to-left

This is a question and an answer :-)

For a long time now I tried using JQM with Hebrew. Getting the Hebrew letter is easy (utf-8 encoding...) , but the thing that didn't work was the alignment..
I mean switching the direction of the elements, the text alignment, positioning etc.

I found many questions about this, but few answers (and the ones I found didn't do a complete job).

Then I found this **excellent** article: 
http://rtl-this.com/tutorial/rtling-hello-world-webpage-rtling

And I implemented it on the css file (more precisely on the one here: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.css ).

That worked :-)

And if I'll figure out how to upload a file, I'll share :-)
I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 9):

You have to make changes to the JavaScript file as well to make sliders and flip switches work properly. Here is the full version of [jQuery Mobile RTL](http://www.intlaqa.com/jquery-mobile-rtl) I made.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently tried to use jQuery mobile to develop an Arabic iOS application with RTL layout, and while jQuery Mobile doesn't support RTL yet, it wasn't too hard to hack the CSS to make it look and act like a proper RTL application.

But I ended up abandoning jQM altogether because, at least as of 1.0.1, the performance was simply unacceptable.

I tried a few hacks like removing all gradients (which helped a little) and disabling animation (which didn't), but it still took a good half a second for the UI to respond to user input.

I'm sure things will improve with the time, but for now at least jQuery Mobile is not an option for me. Its a shame too because it's declarative programming model is so deliciously easy to use.